# Python can't capture element by title selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find the following element shown below in the following URL:

https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba-2018-2019/minnesota-timberwolves-golden-state-warriors-Ye9DTRA7/

I am trying to click on the O/U tab in the URL, which is shown in the image below

[image: over/under]

The current code that I am using is the following:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Over/Under"]').click()
```

However, sometimes this code works and sometimes it doesn't since I get the following exception

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@title="Over/Under"]"}

Is there any alternative solutions ? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: Just edited the post

Comment: It's working for me, I can't reproduce it. Try waiting for the page to fully load and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use some waits after page load.

```
driver.get('https://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba-2018-2019/minnesota-timberwolves-golden-state-warriors-Ye9DTRA7/')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@title='Over/Under']"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```